# Switching views with Transition effect

Tags: xcode, view, effect, uiswitch

I'm trying to add an effect to a switch between 2 views. The switch happen just rotating the device. So far I'm able to apply the effect when from portrait go to landscape, but not viceversa.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)object{
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];
if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{ 
    /* If I run with this block, I have a Exc Bad Access Error and can't run, so I put it 
       under comment

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view  duration:1.0 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view addSubview:self.portraitView];
                    } completion:NULL];
    */ 

    self.view = self.portraitView;

    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

} 
else  if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || deviceOrientation == 
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{   
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view  duration:1 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView];
                    } completion:NULL];
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
}
```

In this way I have the desired effect when passing from Portrait to Landscape, but when I put the device back to Portrait it doesn't load the portraitView, the landscapeView remains on. 
Hope somebody can help me.

EDIT:

I just edited my above code in this way:

```
-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)object{
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];
if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
{ 

    if (self.isViewLoaded  && self.view.window)
    {
    NSLog(@"Portrait1");
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view  duration:1 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        NSLog(@"Portrait2");
                        [self.view.window addSubview:self.portraitView];
                    } completion:NULL];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }   
}
else  if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || deviceOrientation == 
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{   

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view  duration:1 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView];
                    } completion:NULL];
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Landscape");
}
}
```

And the effect works fine. But I have the big issue that when I switch back from Landscape to Portrait the landscapeView remains ON the portraitView. How could I dismiss it?

Comment: I haven't tried it out, but maybe it has something to do with the fact that you're mixing up UIDeviceOrientation and UIInterfaceOrientation, and you're getting lucky in the second if statement.. I can't explain the bad access error though; did you happen to have an NSLog() in there when you were debugging the first if statement?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're saying: I got an error on the [self.view addSubview:self.landscapeView]; line. So I put a NSLog in the line just above that and I see it in the debug window. Is this what you're talking about?

Comment: I edited my code, could you please take a look?

Comment: I was just taking a stab in the dark with my NSLog() question. The reason I asked was I thought maybe you had tried to print theUIDeviceOrientation value (which is an enum, which is really an integer) with a %@ specifier that works only with objects, instead of a %d. This (i.e. using %@ to print an enum) would cause an  Exc Bad Access error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to your updated code, when your device orientation becomes UIDeviceOrientationPortrait, you are making the mistake of adding portraitView as a subview to self.view.window instead of self.view.

Also, what is the purpose behind [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]? You haven't actually presented a modal view controller anywhere, so it doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: The fact is that with self.view I got the Exc Bad Access Error, so I added .window. The [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO] was one of my many shots to try to fix the problem. I canceled it.

Comment: The exact error is: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address= 0xbf7ffffbc) and on the left I got 43664 __37-[ViewController orientationChanged:]_block_invoke_0